# Actionscript - how to test touch events in Windows

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, touch

I code on Actionscript (Adobe Air) and try to test touch events on Windows 7, but It seems doesn't work. How can I test it?

```
this.stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);

private function onSwipe(e:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    trace('touch swipe! ' + e.offsetX);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any other gestures, like pan or zoom? I'm not entirely sure that GESTURE_SWIPE is supported on Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that on Windows. I've never been able to at least.

*The PressAndTapGestureEvent class lets you handle press-and-tap gesture on touch-enabled devices.*

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/PressAndTapGestureEvent.html

Test it on your phone/tablet.

Comment: Thanks! Man on this [video](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/using-native-multitouch-gestures-in-actionscript-3-0/) do it by a touchpad, but it's Mac